# Why won't my random selection without replacement algorithm work?

Tags: for-loop, dart, random

I have made a very simple algorithm that picks a set of numToPick random numbers from the range 0 to batchMax, without replacement. Then it places each selected number in an array called numsPicked. For some reason I cannot explain, it isn't working on DartPad.

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  print(randNoReplace(2, 9));
}

List<int> randNoReplace(int numToPick, int batchMax) {
  List<int> numsPicked = List(numToPick);
  List<int> tmpArray = List(batchMax);
//this for loop creates the tmpArray from 0 to batchMax.
  for (int i = 0; i <= batchMax; i++) {
    tmpArray[i] = i;
  }
//this for loop randomly scrambles said tmpArray.
  for (int i = 0; i <= batchMax; i++) {
    int randIndex = Random().nextInt(batchMax);
    int tmp = tmpArray[i];
    tmpArray[i] = tmpArray[randIndex];
    tmpArray[randIndex] = tmp;
  }
//finally, this for loop adds the first numToPick entries of the scrambled tmpArray and adds them to numsPicked.
  for (int i = 0; i < numToPick; i++) {
    numsPicked[i] = tmpArray[i];
  }
  return numsPicked;
}
```

So, for example, with 2 and 9 respectively, this algorithm should theoretically give me 2 random non-duplicate numbers in the range [0, 9].

Comment: Your two first for-loops are running outside of the size of your Lists. Instead of e.g `for (int i = 0; i <= batchMax; i++)` it should be `for (int i = 0; i < batchMax; i++)` since your index are going from 0 to length - 1. Not sure if that fixes all your problems. Also, this code could be made a lot smaller but I am not sure if this is part of some kind of assignment.

Comment: E.g. the same exact code can be made in a oneliner: `List<int> randNoReplace(int numToPick, int batchMax) => (List.generate(batchMax, (index) => index)..shuffle()).take(numToPick).toList();`

Comment: Omg so dumb, thanks a lot. I just forgot to make the size of tmpArray (batchMax + 1) instead of batchMax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue in your code is that your first two for-loops are going from 0 to
`batchMax` including `batchMax`. This is a problem since you are using `batchMax` to specify the size of your `tmpArray`. Since the index of a `List` starts at 0, we cannot ask for the `batchMax`-element but at most `batchMax - 1`.

So you code should properly be (or `tmpArray should be one element bigger):

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  print(randNoReplace(2, 9));
}

List<int> randNoReplace(int numToPick, int batchMax) {
  List<int> numsPicked = List(numToPick);
  List<int> tmpArray = List(batchMax);
//this for loop creates the tmpArray from 0 to batchMax.
  for (int i = 0; i < batchMax; i++) {
    tmpArray[i] = i;
  }
//this for loop randomly scrambles said tmpArray.
  for (int i = 0; i < batchMax; i++) {
    int randIndex = Random().nextInt(batchMax);
    int tmp = tmpArray[i];
    tmpArray[i] = tmpArray[randIndex];
    tmpArray[randIndex] = tmp;
  }
//finally, this for loop adds the first numToPick entries of the scrambled tmpArray and adds them to numsPicked.
  for (int i = 0; i < numToPick; i++) {
    numsPicked[i] = tmpArray[i];
  }
  return numsPicked;
}
```

Some other minor comments:

- You should properly not initialize a new `Random()` object each time you need a random number. Instead, you should create one instance and reuse it.
- Your code are not making much use of the Dart SDK. In fact, your code could properly be simplified into:

```
void main() {
  print(randNoReplace(2, 9));
}

List<int> randNoReplace(int numToPick, int batchMax) =>
    (List.generate(batchMax, (index) => index)..shuffle())
        .sublist(0, numToPick);
```